# Program can't tell difference between animal?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I have an issue with my learning AI - the program is designed to learn the difference between animals and also add some new animals when prompted. The problem is that I've just found is that the program cannot tell the difference between some form of odd conditional animals (in my case, a pigeon and a kingfisher).

The program is meant to have a unique question stuck to each animal when it is given said animal. For instance, if I say that my animal is a pigeon, then the program will ask for a question, which would be "does it have feathers?" and you can gather the rest

I'll put my code and the problem below. Any help would be a massive +.

```
animalDict = {"Does it swing from trees?":["monkey"], "Does it purr?":["cat"], "Does it have a tail?":["cat","monkey"]}
foundattributes = list()
notpossessed = list()
finalattributes = list()
matches = list()
tempmatches = list()
finalmatches = list()
conflict = list()
def learn():
  print("Computer: I don't know that animal.")
  newAnimal = input("Computer: You were thinking of a(n): ").lower()
  newAttribute = input("Computer: Please input an attribute for this animal, in the form of a question.\n> ").capitalize()
  animalDict[newAttribute]=[newAnimal]
  for attribute in foundattributes:
    if attribute not in notpossessed:
      finalattributes.append(attribute)
  for attribute in finalattributes:
    animalDict[attribute].append(newAnimal)
while True:
  print("Computer: Think of an animal.")
  del foundattributes[:]
  del notpossessed[:]
  del matches[:]
  del conflict[:]
  del finalmatches[:]
  del finalattributes[:]
  for question in sorted(animalDict):
    del tempmatches[:]
    response=input("Computer: %s\n> " % question)
    if response.lower()=="yes":
      if question not in foundattributes:
        foundattributes.append(question)                                            
      for eachAnimal in animalDict[question]:
        if eachAnimal not in matches:
          matches.append(eachAnimal)
        if eachAnimal not in tempmatches:
          tempmatches.append(eachAnimal)                              
      for animal in matches:                                                           
        if animal not in tempmatches:
          matches.remove(animal)
          conflict.append(animal)
    elif response.lower()=="no":
      if question not in notpossessed:
        notpossessed.append(question)
      for animal in animalDict[question]:
        if animal not in conflict:
          conflict.append(animal)
    else:
      print("Computer: I don't understand '%s'"%response)

  for animal in matches:
    if animal not in conflict:
      finalmatches.append(animal)
  for clash in conflict:
    if clash in finalmatches:
      finalmatches.remove(clash)
  if len(finalmatches) == 1:
    conclusion=input("Computer: Is it a %s?\n> "%finalmatches[0])
    if conclusion.lower() == "yes":
      print("Solved!")
    elif conclusion.lower() == "no":
      learn()
    else:
      print("Computer: I don't understand '%s'"%response)
      break
  elif len(finalmatches) <1:
    learn()
  else:
    learn()
```

That is my code. The problem is:

```
Computer: Think of an animal.
Computer: Does it have a tail?
> yes
Computer: Does it purr?
> no
Computer: Does it swing from trees?
> no
Computer: I don't know that animal.
Computer: You were thinking of a(n): pigeon
Computer: Please input an attribute for this animal, in the form of a question.
> does it have feathers?
Computer: Think of an animal.
Computer: Does it have a tail?
> yes
Computer: Does it have feathers?
> yes
Computer: Does it purr?
> no
Computer: Does it swing from trees?
> no
Computer: Is it a pigeon?
> no
Computer: I don't know that animal.
Computer: You were thinking of a(n): kingfisher
Computer: Please input an attribute for this animal, in the form of a question.
> does it eat fish?
Computer: Think of an animal.
Computer: Does it eat fish?
> yes
Computer: Does it have a tail?
> yes
Computer: Does it have feathers?
> yes
Computer: Does it purr?
> no
Computer: Does it swing from trees?
> no
Computer: I don't know that animal.
Computer: You were thinking of a(n):
```

Comment: You should separate it out into different functions instead of having it exist as a long script. I wouldn't be surprised if after doing that, you gain a better understanding of your program and its flaws.

Comment: perhaps use subroutines... (your code is hard to digest)